# Jqgrid Sorting not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting, jqgrid

i created a jqgrid with this follwoing code and i succeeded creating jqgrid without sorting . so i modified the code , but it doesn't sort the data and showing the following error,

```
'firstName' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 1.
```

### Controlller

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = db.customers.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var _Customers = db.customers.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToArray();

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows),
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (from r in _Customers.AsEnumerable()
                    select new
                    {

                        id = r.id,
                        cell = new[] { "<input type='radio' style='cursor:pointer' class='view_Account'  name='selectedCall'  id='" + r.id + "' value='" + r.id + "' />", r.firstName, r.lastName }
                    }
                   ).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

### View

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Customer/GridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['', 'FirstName', 'LastName'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'ssss', width: 20, search: false },
                    { name: 'firstName', sortable: true, sorttype: "text", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] }, width: 180 },
                    { name: 'lastName', sortable: true, sorttype: "text", width: 183 }

                ],
        rowNum: 100,
        width: '200px',
        height: '100px',
        sortname: 'firstName',
        sortorder: "asc",
        pager: jQuery('#pager')
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

var _Customers = db.customers.OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToArray();

You just change the "it." at your order by keywork

Answer (score 1):

rex.

You are missing an attribute in your colmodel.

For sorting to work you need to add an index, like this:

```
{ name: 'firstName', index: 'firstName', sortable: true, sorttype: "text", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] }, width: 180 }
```